# Connect to HornetQ with Apache camel without Spring

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, apache-camel, hornetq

I'm new with Apache camel. I'm trying to connect to a HornetQ queue. I've found several tutorials on this but all use Spring. I have to do it without Spring because the project I'm working on doesn't use Spring. It uses CDI, and I've found this: http://camel.apache.org/cdi.html But I don't understand how to change that so it connects to a queue.
Could anyone help me ??

Comment: There is a camel-sjms component which does not use Spring - http://camel.apache.org/sjms

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use HornetQ, if you can go with ActiveMQ, you can get a serviceMix distribution that has Camel and ActiveMQ.

Comment: We use Jboss, and jboss uses HornetQ.. I really don't have a choice on this. However a friend got it working, I'll add the code sample

Comment: I am running into this issue also - can you post your sample?

Answer (score 0):

After a long and painful history of trying to integrate HornetQ with Camel and employing a programmatic solution at the end, it turned out that at least HornetQ producing can easily be done with the http4 module. Simply send your message payload with the http4 module to the hornetq rest endpoint and everything works fine:

```
http4://hornetqserver:port/hornetq/queues/queuename/create
```